# ' ' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Estou fazendo paginação em um sistema que estou criando usando Django DRF, porém ele gera um erro ao acessar a segunda página, o link é gerado e ao tentar acessar ele me acusa esse erro **'ListaPublicados' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.**

Essa é minha view:

```
class ListaPublicados(ListAPIView):
  permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
  pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
  serializer_class = ListaPublicadosSerializer
  filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
  search_fields = ('titulo')
  ordering_fields = ('titulo')

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    try:
      queryset = models.Anuncio.objects.filter(anuncio_publicado=True)
      queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
      page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

      if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

      serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)
    except Exception as e:
      print('Exception', e)
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Não consegui entender esse erro e não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

Comment: Cara, a mensagem de erro parece clara - a tua `ListaPublicados` precisa ter um atributo `queryset` ou sobrescrever o método `get_queryset()`. Tu tentaste algo para resolver isso?

Comment: Obrigado Leornado, mais é isso que não estou entendendo, sou novo no DRF, mas para mim eu já fiz a denifição do queryset logo abaixo do "TRY:", **queryset = models.Anuncio.objects.filter(anuncio_publicado=True)**. Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

Nunca trabalhei com python ou django, mas eu imagino que a definição do `queryset` (que, no teu caso, está dentro do `try` que fica no método `list`) tenha que estar fora do escopo do método `list`. Do jeito que está, `queryset` é variável local, e não da classe `ListaPublicados`.

Tenta algo assim:

```
class ListaPublicados(ListAPIView):
  permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
  pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
  serializer_class = ListaPublicadosSerializer
  filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
  search_fields = ('titulo')
  ordering_fields = ('titulo')
  queryset = ## não sei que valor poderia ter aqui - talvez um null, ou aquele models.Anuncio que tu colocaste mais abaixo, sei lá...

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    try:
      queryset = models.Anuncio.objects.filter(anuncio_publicado=True)
      queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
      page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

      if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

      serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)
    except Exception as e:
      print('Exception', e)
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui entender o que estava acontecendo, era bem nessa lógica que o Leornado falou, porém tinha que adicionar um metodo queryset a mais

```
class ListaPublicados(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
  pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
  serializer_class = ListaPublicadosSerializer
  filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
  search_fields = ('titulo')
  ordering_fields = ('titulo')
  queryset = models.Anuncio.objects.filter(anuncio_publicado=True)

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Retornar a lista de anuncios publicados
    try:
      queryset = self.get_queryset()
      queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
      page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

      if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

      serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as e:
      print('Exception', e)
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Tive que alterar a **ListAPIView** por **generics.ListCreateAPIView**, colocaro queryset para a variavel global da class e na função chamar o self.queryset().

Obrigado pela ajuda!!!